# Can I store a ordered queue in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, spark-streaming, scheduler, priority-queue

I am working on developing a job scheduler, for real time data ( which in total can be 20-30 M) . I want to maintain a priority queue for all of them to decide which data to be send first. The priority queue should be able to hold this large amount of data.
Is this possible in spark to hold this data in the order.
Or are there any other way out ?

Answer (score -1):

A priority queue is just an ordered list of items. Using spark / spark spark sql you can select from the dataframe and specify the sort order and limit (for example to dequeue a single item). If you will be constantly querying the data, make sure you cache the data frame.

Consider a simplified table in spark named `priority_queue` like this:

```
id    |    priority    |   date_added
1            1             3/15/2018 00:00:00
2            2             3/15/2015 00:01:00
...
```

You can get top x items with `val topn = spark.sql("select * from priority_queue order by priority, date_added limit x")`

Then create a temp table from `topn` and `spark.sql("delete from priority_queue where id in (select  id from topn)")`